# DNS Redirect Website to another Server

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, mx-record, cname-record, spf

I have two servers, server 1 and server2.
The name serververs of the domain points to server1.

**1.I have this configuration regarding Server1 DNS Zones:**

```
domain.com. 1200    IN  A   server2-ip  Edit   Delete

localhost.domain.com.   14400   IN  A   127.0.0.1   Edit   Delete

www.domain.com. 1200    IN  CNAME   domain.com  Edit   Delete

ftp.domain.com. 1200    IN  CNAME   domain.com  Edit   Delete

webdisk.domain.com. 1200    IN  A   server2-ip  Edit   Delete

autodiscover.domain.com.    1200    IN  A   server2-ip  Edit   Delete

autoconfig.domain.com.  1200    IN  A   server2-ip  Edit   Delete

domain.com. 1200    IN  TXT v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:server1-ip ?all  Edit   Delete

mail.domain.com.    1200    IN  A   server1-ip  Edit   Delete
```

**2. And I have this configuration regarding Server2 DNS Zone:**

```
domain.com. 1200    IN  A   server2-ip  Edit   Delete

www.domain.com. 1200    IN  CNAME   domain.com  Edit   Delete

ftp.domain.com. 1200    IN  A   server2-ip  Edit   Delete

cpanel.domain.com.  1200    IN  A   server2-ip  Edit   Delete

webdisk.domain.com. 1200    IN  A   server2-ip  Edit   Delete

whm.domain.com. 1200    IN  A   server2-ip  Edit   Delete

webmail.domain.com. 1200    IN  A   server2-ip  Edit   Delete

domain.com. 1200    IN  TXT v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:server1-ip ?all  Edit   Delete

mail.domain.com.    1200    IN  A   server1-ip  Edit   Delete
```

- I also set the MX Entry for server1 to point Local, to mail.domain.com , and for server2 to point remote to mail.domain.com.**
- The emails works good. Email is set to server1, but the website should work from server2 and it works still from server1. What's wrong? :D**

Comment: Did you wait several hours (depends on your timeout setting in DNS) to propagate the change? What ip address does the www.domain.com resolve to on your client machine?

Comment: I think that the problem is that the domain have only the name servers of the first server, and I should add also the name servers of the second server. Am I right?

Comment: You probably should change the nameserver but that is another issue.  With this config the webserver should be server2 after you have left time for caching to expire.  Are the nameservers pointing to this dns at all?

Comment: the name servers only points to server1, and from server1 I created some dns records that points to server2

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed. It works. It seems that my browser cache displayed the website from the old server. Now it displays the website from the new server.

Like Kamil Šrot mentioned, we need to wait a few hours for the domain to propagate the dns records change.